# How should OP handle so-so / unhelpful edit that was reviewed / accepted?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

This happens occasionally, where an edit is seemingly casually approved but does not improve anything about the question. In this case [the suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7323804) was to add the [stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdin) tag.  Comment: "please max tags 5".

> #### [Print a web page through Google cloud print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819831/node-js-data-input-stream)
>
> Is there a input stream extension so I can call methods like I am used
>   to
>
> For example
>
> ```
> stdin.read(function (err, buffer) { // err if an error event was created, buffer if this is just data, null to both if the end of the stream was reached.
>     // Added bonuses would be other methods I am used to in Java
>     // - readLine
>     // - readFully
>     // - readStringUtf8
>     // - readInt, readDouble, readBoolean, etc.
> })
> ```
>
> The backend would be listening for `data`, `end`, and `error` events
>   and automatically buffer them and just have them available for when I
>   call `read`.
>
> Existing Tags: [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) [module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/module) [stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stream) [extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extend)

The question applies to streams in general, not specifically to [stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdin), so I feel that the tag slightly reduces the clarity of the question.

I really thought the edits were supposed to be a 'clear improvement', and 'wash' or 'so-so' edits should be rejected.

Maybe I'm wrong. Since it happened to me more than once I thought I would bring up some suggestions:

- A way to notify those who accepted the edit that they should be more careful.
- The system should require more than a 3-vs-2 majority for accepting an edit.
- We could notify the original author of the edit, but if his edit was rejected to begin with, there might already be a mechanism for this.

I just rolled back the edit for now, but if there's anything else I should do let me know.

Comment: Re. "notify the original author", you can @ reply them if the edit was accepted, giving you a way to inform them that that was an invalid edit and explain to them why it was invalid.

Comment: Nice. I didn't realize we could do that without them commenting first.

Comment: Indeed you can. On a side note, glancing through their activities > revisions... It looks like this user has done this quite often. I'm unsure if this is bad enough to need a moderator flag, but it's definitely bad editing.